# How does sales tax on a cross-state vehicle sale work?

Tags: united-states, sales-tax, massachusetts, connecticut

I am thinking of buying a boat in Connecticut and moving it to Massachusetts. The dealer says I pay no sales tax in Connecticut, only when I register it in Massachusetts do I pay.

Is this true? I would have thought that any vehicle sale in Connecticut would result in tax being collected.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's how auto sales work, so I wouldn't be surprised about boat sales operating the same way.

Comment: US -There was a case a few years back where a judge bought and registered a boat in a state where it wasn't subject to tax. He didn't declare it in his home state so he avoided the property taxes ... until he got caught and spent some time in the crowbar inn for tax evasion. As a judge, he didn't even have the excuse that he didn't know the law

Comment: @pojo-guy - if he'd *kept* it in the other state, he probably would have been fine.

Comment: I wish I could dig up the article, but it's been long enough it's fallen to the bottom of the bit bucket.

Comment: The cost will probably end up the same. Either pay sales tax in the first state, and then pay a use tax with a credit equal to the first states sales tax in the second state; or the first state exempts you from sales tax because the boat is quickly moved to the second state and then the 2nd state charges you sales tax.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.
For cars, Edmunds have an article about the issues:
https://www.edmunds.com/car-buying/should-i-buy-an-out-of-state-car.html